# How to add data as a row in the database getting from the hash map

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, hashmap, simpleadapter

I want to try add the data as a row in the database.but I am unable to add it as a row.

This is my logcat I want to add data in the database like below :-

```
10-20 10:49:43.311 12107-12107/com.refresh.pos E/key..::>>: quantity
10-20 10:49:43.311 12107-12107/com.refresh.pos E/value..::>>: 1
10-20 10:49:43.311 12107-12107/com.refresh.pos E/key..::>>: price
10-20 10:49:43.311 12107-12107/com.refresh.pos E/value..::>>: 10.0
10-20 10:49:43.311 12107-12107/com.refresh.pos E/key..::>>: name
10-20 10:49:43.311 12107-12107/com.refresh.pos E/value..::>>: bnana
10-20 10:49:43.311 12107-12107/com.refresh.pos E/key..::>>: quantity
10-20 10:49:43.311 12107-12107/com.refresh.pos E/value..::>>: 1
10-20 10:49:43.311 12107-12107/com.refresh.pos E/key..::>>: price
10-20 10:49:43.312 12107-12107/com.refresh.pos E/value..::>>: 15.0
10-20 10:49:43.312 12107-12107/com.refresh.pos E/key..::>>: name
10-20 10:49:43.312 12107-12107/com.refresh.pos E/value..::>>: lemon
```

I want to add item in database like :-

```
three fields :- quantity   price     name
                  1        10.0      bnana
                  1        15.0      lemon
```

I hope anyone understand now what I want to do.

This is the code by which I am setting the adapter to the listview and getting the key and value from the Map :-

```
private void showList(List<LineItem> list) {

    saleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (LineItem line : list) {
        saleList.add(line.toMap());
    }


    SimpleAdapter sAdap;
    sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), saleList,
            R.layout.listview_lineitem, new String[]{"name", "quantity", "price"}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.quantity, R.id.price});
    saleListView.setAdapter(sAdap);

    for (Map<String, String> map : saleList) {

        Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();

            Log.e("key..::>>", "" + pair.getKey());
            Log.e("value..::>>", "" + pair.getValue());


        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I add the data as a row which I am getting in the form of key and value.

Comment: have you created a database, if yes, please post its code

Comment: @SahilManchanda yes ! please see my updated code.but my problem is how can i insert the data as i mentioned above.

Comment: "map" in your code is the "row" you want. And, no need for iterator. map.get("name") etc is enough.

Comment: @Toris then how can i add the data as a row in the database getting from the map.

Comment: @LoveAndroid pojoSell is the db row? If so, pojoSell.setProductname(map.get("name")); etc.